# Referencing a .NET 3.5 created DLL in VBA (Access)

Tags: .net, vba, interop

I have created a small class library using .net 3.5  which builds a DLL that I want to use in an Access 2003 database.
I have checked the Register for COM interop in the Compile options.

Once the Build is done,  there is dll and tlb file created.

I now reference the TLB file in my access database and it works with no issues when it is done on my developer machine.

The problem arises when I try to open the Access application (runtime) on a different machine.
I made sure that the DLL and TLB files are located in a location on a server that is accessible from both machines.

I get an error saying that the project contains a missing or broken referenc to the file 'blahblah.tlb' version 1.0.

I am fairly new to .NET programming and any help would be hugely appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you register the files with COM on the machine that you're using to run the code?

Answer (score 0):

COM DLL's need to be registered on each machine.  Try running the following command from a command line on your target system:  (`regsvr32.exe` is in `c:\windows\system32\`)

```
regsvr32 blahblah.dll
```